# Some Sections in the Structure Pane are Highlighted Red

Tags: texstudio

Being a newbie to LaTeX, while adding a new page to an existing Latex template using TeXstudio some sections of the document turned red in the Structure Pane. Kindly someone may explain the reason behind and potential consequence if any.

Comment: What do you mean by *in the Structure Pane*? What editor are you using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Sigure Sorry for not mentioning it earlier, I am using TeXstudio and there is a Panel on left side which displays the structure of document.

Comment: The only thing I can find is that sections are coloured if they are part of the appendix. Have you added `\appendix` before these sections?

Comment: A restart of the studio turned things back to normal. Thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a new section to the TeXStudio would highlight all other sections that are affected by the change. E.g. Adding a numbered section would red highlight existing numbered sections in the document. A restart of the studio will display it as usual.

P.S. It was kind of silly question, but may help other fools like me.

Comment: i found this very useful, thanks. One point to add: 
if you have subfiles in TexStudio and just recently added them, compiling while this subfile is active will give all errors associated with not being a complete document. Once I restarted TeXStudio as per your suggestion it correctly associated the open main document to be compiled.